# Advice about windows phone 8 and SharePoint 2010 application?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-phone-8

I want to develop a windows phone 8 application that will communicate with sharepoint 2010 server. I’m familiar with windows phone 8 development. But no previous experience about sharepoint. While start searching information regarding this issue, I found windows phone 7 and sharepoint 2010 related info. Again windows phone 8 and sharepoint 2013 related info.

So is it a right chose to develop an application for windows phone 8 and sharepoint 2010? I guess it must be possible. Please advice where can I find more information about this combination.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pull data from Sharepoint and render it in some way in your mobile app.

If that is the case depending of the technologies you use to develop your app you can choose between using Sharepoint Client Object Model, or alternatively Sharepoint exposes a lot of webservices to query data.

What I have been doing lately is I actually deploy own api using service stack which allows my client to consume json data, if you dont have experience with Sharepoint I would avoid this method and stick with what its in the box.

Comment: Actually I managed to install local SharePoint server as virtual machine. Now I'm reaching heavily with SP. So got little experience with SP. Now lacking knowledge of widows api and examples to excrement farther. Could find any code that that shows signin to SP server. And also nothing how to retrieve data form SP.

Comment: Could you please kindly share some code to show basic data manipulation with SP server. If you do so it would be my project & as well as life saver :). Because my continuous search result is zero for last couple of days. I also asked question if various forum, no response. Ur reply give me grate hope.